# Jenkins, read information from another job

Tags: jenkins, groovy, hudson, jenkins-pipeline

I have a job "Project-A" in Jenkins which runs every 1 hour. I have another job "Project-B" which runs once in a day. When the job "Project-B" is triggered, I will pass "project-A" name as parameter, it will read the last successful build information of Project-A, such as build_id, in which slave node the build was run, timestamp etc. I am doing this via curl and Jenkins API.

Would like to know is there any better way to do this. Instead of curl. groovy or anything better? or any plugins to achieve this.

Thanks